# Any plugin for converting web-based satellite imagery into ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, georeferencing, software-recommendations, google-earth, google

I recently lost an Add-In toolbar that displayed imagery in ArcMap where I could assign projection to the data frame and my drawings on the satellite images would be "accurate" (vs drawing in a WGS projection where I need to be accurate to the half-acre).

I REALLY don't want to go through the pain of georeferencing every image I need at the correct scale/resolution just to get it into ArcMap, as I cover a lot of ground. Is there any plugin out there that can convert an image more easily into the correct projection WITHOUT using the georeferencing tool for every little piece of imagery, especially since the hi-res stuff I need/want to use is mostly in Landvis/Google Earth (that work off of snapshots, not downloading rasters).

Comment: What's wrong with world imagery from ArcGis online?

Comment: I need imagery that is more monthly than yearly, and I need to know when it was taken.